# Counting number of sequences of particular value for multiple columns in a data frame

Tags: r, count, sequence

I would like to create a table or a new data frame that displays, for each column in the original data frame (of which there are many), how many times a sequence of a specific value occurs. For example, if I have the following data frame:

```
x <- data.frame("Red" = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d"), "Blue" = c("b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), "Green" = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"))
```

and I want to know, for each color (Red, Blue, and Green) how many times a run of the value "a" occurs (i.e., before it is interrupted by another value like b or c)

The correct answer would look something like this:

```
     Color a_sequences
1   Red  2
2  Blue  1
3 Green  3
```

I have found solutions on this site using the rle function on single vectors but I don't know how to scale this up for an entire data frame with multiple columns and obtain a new table or data frame with the sequence counts, as in the above table. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
f = function(v, ch) sum(rle(as.character(v))$values == ch)
sapply(x, f, 'a')
# Red  Blue Green 
# 2     1     3
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you guide me on how to put this output in the format of a new table or df?

Comment: wrap in `data.frame(lapply(x, f, 'a'))` if you want values in columns.  Or `cbind(sapply(x, f, 'a'))` if you want them arranged as rows

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tidyverse` where we `gather` into 'long' format, grouped by 'color', and the run-length-id (`rleid`) of 'value', `filter` the 'value' elements that are 'a', then grouped by 'color', get the number of distinct 'grp' elements

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
gather(x, color, value) %>% 
   group_by(color, grp = rleid(value)) %>% 
   filter(value == "a") %>% 
   group_by(color) %>%
   summarise(n = n_distinct(grp))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  color     n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 Blue      1
#2 Green     3
#3 Red       2
```

---

Or an option with `summarise_all`

```
x %>% 
   summarise_all(list(~ n_distinct(setdiff((. == 'a') * rleid(.), 0)))) %>% 
   as.list %>% 
   enframe %>%
   unnest
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  name  value
#  <chr> <int>
#1 Red       2
#2 Blue      1
#3 Green     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea. We can combine and collapse all string, split the string that is not `a`, and count how many elements containing `a`. `result2` is the final outcome.

```
result <- sapply(x, function(x) {
  x2 <- as.character(x)
  y <- paste0(x2, collapse = "")
  z <- strsplit(y, "[^a]")[[1]]
  return(sum(grepl("a", z)))
})

result2 <- data.frame(Color = names(result), a_sequence = unname(result))
result2
#   Color a_sequence
# 1   Red          2
# 2  Blue          1
# 3 Green          3
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R you could do:

```
 f = as.character(unique(unlist(x))) 
 t(sapply(x,function(y)table(factor(rle(as.character(y))$values,f))))
      a b c d
Red   2 1 1 1
Blue  1 1 0 0
Green 3 2 0 0
```

It seems your whole dataset is in factors so the code `as.character()` is used